# How to assign values to 2-D array?

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I have 2-D array:

```
String[][] letters = new String[5][5];
```

Also I have array with English alphabet.

```
String[] alphabet = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", ...};
```

How to fill 2-D array with letters from alphabet?
I excpect something like that:

```
{a, b, c, d, e},
{f, g, h, i, j},
{k, l, m, n, o},
{p, q, r, s, t},
{u, v, w, x, y};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        letters[i][j] = alphabet[i*5 + j];
    }
}
```

Of course, the `"z"` will not be stored in the 2D array, but you already knew that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in a simple way:

```
String letters[][] = {{"a","b"},{"c","d"}};
```